# Using Inspire in experience

Tags: grammar

Past work experience and the current work inspire me to explore further on project management skills.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Some problems here. With regard to your next employer, all work is past, there is no current work. Use inspire in the interview, but in writing, it's overblown. The whole sentence is not needed, frankly. To explore project management further is to say you have not done that work.

Comment: You can explore x skills further, not explore further on x skills. But using the word inspire is like saying you are so excited to work for me that you worship me. Not suitable. Use a milder word: propel, push, prompt, encourage.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/561464/inspire-in-sentence