# Inspire in sentence

Tags: grammar

I am writing a sentence to say past work and current work leads me to research  further on topic.

My past experience and current work inspire me to explore further in chemistry.

Comment: "Inspire" is used reasonably well, but the sentence has other problems.

Comment: "to explore further on chemistry" isn't right.

Comment: "inspire me to explore chemistry further"

Comment: The “on” variant says that you want to explore something (else) while using chemistry. The juxtaposition of “on” with “chemistry” sounds like a euphemism for taking drugs. *Cf* “you can go further on petrol”.

Comment: @Lawrence Not sure I understand your first sentence - e.g? But I agree with the second one.

Comment: The OP’s sentence was “... on chemistry” at the time of my earlier comment.